# infinite loop started , Why?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am using following code to find sum of digits in Python but infinite loop gets started as I run program

```
def digit_sum(n):
    k=str(n)
    i=0
    while i<range(len(k)):
        l=int(i)
        j=0
        j=j+i
        print j
        i+=1

digit_sum(1234)
```

Comment: please post your code and error message as text. It looks like you have an indentation error.

Comment: i < range(len(k)) is wrong. You're comparing a constant with a generator.

Comment: As here the wrong indentation was the source of the error, editing to correct the indentation makes both the question and the answers meaningless. I'm wondering whether it would be better to roll back ...

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error.

So, for getting correct output try this way . You can check this code [here](https://repl.it/KQ0Q/4) .

```
def digit_sum(n):
    k = str(n)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(k):
        l = int(k[i])
        j = j + l
        i += 1
    print j

digit_sum(1234)
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong. The while loop is outside of your function. Indent it to stay inside the function. Also give more meaningful names to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are new to python So i m going to help you out i have seen you code it seems like you have indentation problem and some logic problem also so i have updated it see it here

```
def digit_sum(n):
  k = str(n)
  j = 0 #sum for digits
  i  = 0
  while i in range(len(k)):
    #Add convert string to the int and add to the sum
    j = j + int(k[i]);
    #increment Counter
    i = i+1
    print j # print Sum
digit_sum(1234)
```

For more info about indentation you can [See Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)

Comment: @MohitMalik just to note that outside of this being an excercise, you would write this as `sum(int(ch) for ch in str(n))`

Comment: @MohitMalik range function returns a sequence so when its called it will return sequence from 0 to len(k) which iterable so it is used using in if you are familiar with java it is like for each function and also you can use while i < len(K): will do the same